# How to implement network service identification, check if service is as expected (like TCP handshake)

Tags: network-programming, protocols, ipc, network-protocols, zeromq

I am implementing service with ZeroMQ (a good abstraction over networking). Ideally it would be cool if client can determine if server is what expected.

Example:

There are 3 services:

1. Sum service. (running on port 50001)
2. Multiply service. (running on port 50002)
3. Power service. (running on port 50003)

But there is a case, when services running not on default ports, because another services acquired these ports.

For better reliability of program this case should be handled.

How do I check if service is what expected? I mean a standard, best-ever algorithm (or keywords to find it).

My idea about the algorithm (can be much imperfect):

1. Client send handshake, that contain above all an identificator of service.
2. Client wait for response for timeout (for ex. 30 seconds)
3. Server responds properly.
4. Okay, client start communication.

Exceptions:

- incorrect response
- time out

Comment: Use a Service Discovery

Comment: I do something like this. I have a large number of different packets in my topology that I use for my db server (gotta keep the db separate from the gateway ... no hackers on my system get any access to the db) and for servers telling each other about stuff like client accounts etc.

As part of the start up sequence, I put a ServerId packet on the wire on the output sockets of each server so that when they connect to one another, a single packet is sent. It's kinda small, about 40 bytes but contains my system header, a unique server id, and the name of that server and print who has connected.